# After getting input string from the user, output includes some other character(s)

Tags: c, arrays, string, gets, puts

I decelerate a matrix of chars

```
char strs[3][200] = {'\0'};
```

and then try to insert string just for the first row

```
gets(strs[0]);
```

and then try to print all the rows

```
printf("1) ");
puts(strs[0]);
printf("2) ");
puts(strs[1]);
printf("3) ");
puts(strs[2]);
```

The result is

```
1) ☺me input from the user
2) ☺
3) ☺
```

why there is a "smiley" in the result ☺?

Comment: `gets()` is danger. use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: Try `char strs[3][200] = {{'\0'}};`. If that didn't work, then provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). BTW, your input and result do not match.

Comment: From where did you get 4th output? It appears your source file contains some wierd character.

Comment: Smiley faces are the characters with codes 1 and 2 in the DOS charset. Are you trying something fancy that you don't show us, like incrementing `strs[0][0]++` or some such?

Comment: Your code cannot compile, because of puts and gets want char pointer.

Comment: @LPs: and what is `strs[0]` out of an initialization as `strs[3][200]`?

Comment: @Jongware sorry, I'm not getting you...

Comment: @LPs , `strs[0]` *is* a char pointer.

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str[3][200]={{'\0'},{'\0'},{'\0'}};

    fgets(str[0], 200, stdin);
    fgets(str[1], 200, stdin);
    fgets(str[2], 200, stdin);

    fputs(str[0], stdout);
    fputs(str[1], stdout);
    fputs(str[2], stdout);


    return 0;
}
```

In your code you initialized only the first element/string. Then when you have garbage in your strings.

Comment: Yes. My mistake. Need coffe before start my brain :)

Answer (score -1):

> Look like some thing went wrong in initialization.

try this

```
char options[2][100];

    options[0][0]='t';
    options[0][1]='e';    
    options[0][2]='s';
    options[0][3]='t';
    options[0][4]='1';
    options[0][5]='\0';

        printf("1) ");
        puts(options[0]);
```

> Out put will be :

```
1) test1
```